# Can't get read.csv() output to dissapear?

Tags: r, csv, pdf, r-markdown

I've been trying to create a PDF R markdown, and no matter which command I've used, I can't seem to get the output of this CV (which is quite substantial) to disappear from the R markdown.

```
{r include=FALSE, echo = FALSE, results='hide'}
brexit=read.csv('C:\\Users\\Kai\\Desktop\\Statistical learning\\Assessed Practical 2\\brexit.csv')
```

any help as to how I can prevent the CSV data printing in the R markdown would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: here is the link to the .rmd file and the PDF!

https://github.com/kai-lawsonmcdowall/Brexit_analysis

Comment: Is this all of your code? Normally this would not result in the file being printed unless there was a subsequent line with just `brexit` or error messages.

Comment: Nothing should be displayed with those chunk options, please post the fill Rmarkdown file to see if there are overriding PDF options

Comment: Thanks both, @dcarlson  that is all the code for that particular chunk, as far as i can tell when I run it line by line I get the error "Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name" for the first line. However for all the other chunks with similar code I get this error and they seem to work in the markdown fine, otherwise there is no other line with `brexit`. @DanielJachetta wasn't sure the best way to include the .rmd file, so I've uploaded the .rmd and pdf to my GitHub and included the link, I hope that helps!

Comment: In your .rmd file you are telling the code to print the csv file with the last line in the chunk: ````{r include=FALSE, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide',collapse=TRUE, }
````
````library(data.table)
````
````brexit=fread('C:\\Users\\Kai\\Desktop\\Statistical learning\\Assessed Practical 2\\brexit.csv')
````
````brexit
````

Comment: Remove line 35 from your markdown document https://github.com/kai-lawsonmcdowall/Brexit_analysis/blob/main/brexit%20analysis.Rmd#L35 That is priting the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for your answers! @Ronak Shah even following the removal of brexit on line 35 it did still seem to print, I eventually removed line 41, as.data.frame(brexit) from the second chunk and that seemed to work!

```
{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
as.data.frame(brexit)
brexitglm <- glm(formula = voteBrexit~abc1+notBornUK+medianIncome+medianAge+withHigherEd,  family = binomial, data = brexit) #performing the logistic regression
summary(brexitglm)
```

Comment: Yep.  If you are not assigning it to a variable, you are sending it to print.

Comment: Thanks @DanSlone! I realized I should've done brexitglm <- as.data.frame(brexitglm) now.